# How I have to connect datasource of a UITableView in a xib?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I know how to connect the datasource of a TableView in a Sotryboard, but not in a xib. I connect the datasource of my table with the viewController, and when I run it I get a SIGABRT. Is it enough? Do I have to write some code for the xib?

Comment: I have to say that the tableview is in a Storyboard, of a new class that had a xib before.

Comment: Your question is quite confusing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .h file of your class adopt TableView protocols like this.

```
 @interface EditProject : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

When you connect datasource,delegate of `UITableView` at run time it will try to find these delegate and datasource methods if you have not written them then your application will crash.

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 

{
  //datasource method.
   return 5;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {

  //delegate method.

 }
```

In .xib you do like this. Right Click on `UITableView` Controller and connect datasource and delegate to File's Owner.

[image]

Comment: Ok, but in the xib have I to connect the datasource to the view?

Comment: Updated question, Is it what you are asking?

Comment: It works! Thank you so much anonymous, because it was driving me crazy!

Comment: ANYTIME... Happy coding. :-))

Answer (score 0):

Implement a class the follows the UITableViewDataSource Protocol, and provide the data via the protocol methods.